# DecodeError when training a TensorFlow BoostedTreesClassifier with a big dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, decision-tree

I have been fighting a strange `DecodeError` when training a `BoostedTreesClassifier` in Tensorflow, with a big dataset (~30M rows). I'm convinced that it has to do with the size of the training set because I have no issues if I reduce it to, let's say, 10M rows. In addition, I have no NaNs in the dataset.

I am trying to manipulate the batch parameters for both the input function and classifier, but I haven't yet understood properly some parameters and functions, namely: `n_batches_per_layer` and functions `shuffle(buffer_size)` and `batch(batch_size)`.

Does anyone have any suggestion or can anyone give me some hints on these parameters/functions?

My Tensorflow version is 2.2.0.

---

**Error:**

```
File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3053, in _as_graph_def
        graph.ParseFromString(compat.as_bytes(data))
    google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

**Input Function**

This is my current input function - I'm playing with the bach size and shuffle value, but without changes. These are examples:

```py
 def input_fn():
            dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(x), y))
            if shuffle:
                dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000)

            dataset = dataset.repeat(None)
            dataset = dataset.batch(10000)

            return dataset
```

**Classifier:**

This is how I am using the classifier. Once again, I've been playing with `n_batches_per_layer`.

```py
    params = {
        'n_trees': 10,
        'max_depth': 3,
        'n_batches_per_layer': 1,            
        'center_bias': False
    }

    params = dict(params)

    # classifier
    gbt_est = tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier(tf_feature_columns, **params)

    # training
    gbt_est.train(train_input_fn)
    print(gbt_est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)) # NB: it crashes before printing this

    # evaluation
    results = gbt_est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)
```

**Error log:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../src/Main.py", line 11, in <module>
    controller.train()
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/src/controller/ModelController.py", line 62, in train
    gbt_model.train_gbt_model()
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/src/ml_model/TensorFlowModel.py", line 78, in train_gbt_model
    self._train_with_gbt_classifier_v2(train_input_fn, eval_input_fn, save_model=False)
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/src/ml_model/TensorFlowModel.py", line 292, in _train_with_gbt_classifier_v2
    gbt_est.train(train_input_fn)
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 349, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1182, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1213, in _train_model_default
    return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1502, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    with training.MonitoredTrainingSession(
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 601, in MonitoredTrainingSession
    return MonitoredSession(
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1034, in __init__
    super(MonitoredSession, self).__init__(
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 737, in __init__
    h.begin()
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 563, in begin
    self._summary_writer = SummaryWriterCache.get(self._checkpoint_dir)
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer_cache.py", line 62, in get
    FileWriterCache._cache[logdir] = FileWriter(
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py", line 372, in __init__
    super(FileWriter, self).__init__(event_writer, graph, graph_def)
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.add_graph(graph=graph, graph_def=graph_def)
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py", line 194, in add_graph
    true_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def(add_shapes=True)
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3136, in as_graph_def
    result, _ = self._as_graph_def(from_version, add_shapes)
  File "/home/myuser/gbt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3053, in _as_graph_def
    graph.ParseFromString(compat.as_bytes(data))
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Comment: @EmreI ended up splitting the data into batches. Then, with multiple training interactions, I've successfully trained my model.

Comment: You might like to submit the details in an answer.